# Why should I use viewmodelproviders for viewmodels?

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

Why should I use viewmodelproviders for viewmodels?

Why I just can't add custom singleton annotation to my viewmodel, and then inject this viewmodel to fragment class?

Like so:

```
@MainScope
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel()
```

And then:

```
open class BaseFragment<T: ViewModel>: DaggerFragment() {
@Inject
protected lateinit var viewModel: T
```

Both cases are independent of screen rotation.

Is there any drawbacks of singleton annotation case?
I see only advantages, with this approach I don't need to copy/paste tons of code.

Comment: I use a ViewModelFactory with Dagger and ViewModelProviders, and it works well.  See here for more info: https://proandroiddev.com/viewmodel-with-dagger2-architecture-components-2e06f06c9455

Comment: I also use it, and it works well. But I don't understand why should I use it. It requires at least 3 copy/paste classes.

Comment: Dagger scoping and injecting also works well. 
As I know - ViewModelProviders is the helper class, whose main purpose is to create new instance of viewmodel if it is not exist, otherwise return existing instance.

Comment: Dagger with scoping can do the same, but without additional classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why should I use viewmodelproviders for viewmodels?

To get `viewModel.onCleared()` callback called properly at the right time by the `ComponentActivity`.

(and to ensure it's created only once for the given ViewModelStoreOwner).

> Why I just can't add custom singleton annotation to my viewmodel, and then inject this viewmodel to fragment class?

Because you won't get `viewModel.onCleared()` callback called properly at the right time by the `ComponentActivity`.

> Is there any drawbacks of singleton annotation case? I see only advantages,

That you don't get `viewModel.onCleared()`.

Also if you have a singleton variant, then the ViewModel won't die along with its enclosing finishing Activity, and stay alive even on back navigation (which is probably not intended).

> with this approach I don't need to copy/paste tons of code.

You're using Kotlin. Use extension functions.